# Flask reading Dict

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I think I'm missing something with Flask. I want to read my dictionary which is a static file to a basic template and make it appear with Flask. Any idea why I'm getting an error? Thanks!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html, switch=switchList')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's my main.html

```
<body>
    {% block content %}
    
    {% for switch in switches %}
    Switch Name: {{ switch.name }} <br>
      - Serial: {{ switch.serial }} <br>
      - Reachable at: {{ switch.ip }} <br>
      <br>
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

here's the the dict database

```
switchList = [
        {
        "name": "C9200",
        "serial": "L3143S",
        "ip": "192.168.1.1",
        "check": True,
        "total": 28,
        "up": 10,
        "down": 5,
        "disabled": 13,
        "capacity": 35       
    },
    {
        "name": "C9300",
        "serial": "ASDSADA5",
        "ip": "172.168.44.2",
        "check": False,
        "total": 48,
        "up": 32,
        "down": 6,
        "disabled": 10,  
        "capacity": 67       
    },
]
```

Comment: render_template('main.html, switch=switchList') 

Change to switches=switchList

Comment: Attaching the error you are getting would be useful

Comment: changed getting the same error "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: main.html, switches=switchList". Also, my dictionary file is the root if that matters.

Comment: `return render_template('main.html, switch=switchList')` You've got the ending quote in the wrong place.  It should be `return render_template('main.html', switch=switchList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja will render a python object into html. Your issue is that your dictionary isn't being loaded as a python object, thus it cannot be served to your page. **Solution, load your dictionary and pass through your html template:**

```
...

# Load your dict – be sure to enter the correct path
with open('static/switchList.json', 'r') as f:
    switchList = json.loads(f)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html', switch=switchList)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `switchList` holds the data you want to show, change

```
return render_template('main.html, switch=switchList')
```

to

```
return render_template('main.html', switch=switchList)
```